# Select records that changed their last values

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I register the history of the price of products in a catalog (another table).

The price of any product can change at any moment so I need to identify only what products have changed their prices the last time. For example I have this table:

```
+----+--------------+-------+---------------------+
| id | product_code | price | price_date          |
+----+--------------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | P01          | 10.00 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 | P01          | 15.00 | 2019-01-03 00:00:00 |
|  3 | P01          | 20.00 | 2019-01-05 00:00:00 |
|  4 | P01          | 15.00 | 2019-01-09 00:00:00 |
|  5 | P02          | 10.00 | 2019-01-04 00:00:00 |
|  6 | P02          | 15.00 | 2019-01-06 00:00:00 |
|  7 | P02          | 15.00 | 2019-01-07 00:00:00 |
|  8 | P03          | 15.00 | 2019-01-09 00:00:00 |
|  9 | P04          | 15.00 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 10 | P04          | 15.00 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 11 | P04          | 25.00 | 2019-01-05 00:00:00 |
| 12 | P05          | 15.00 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 13 | P05          | 15.00 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------+-------+---------------------+
```

and I need this result (i need the penultimate and last price of each product IF they are different, if they are the same ignore the product):

```
+--------------+-------+---------------------+
| product_code | price | price_date          |
+--------------+-------+---------------------+
|          P01 | 20.00 | 2019-01-05 00:00:00 |
|          P01 | 15.00 | 2019-01-09 00:00:00 |
|          P04 | 15.00 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |
|          P04 | 25.00 | 2019-01-05 00:00:00 |
+--------------+-------+---------------------+
```

and this are the exceptions:

> P02 didn't change its price so I ignore it (yes, the same price can be registered multiple times consecutively)
>
> P03 only have 1 register, so technically didn't change its price, so I ignore it (this are very rare but some products never change their prices)
>
> P05 didn't change its price so I ignore it

I put this data in order to read easily but technically the data can be in any order.

I send you the query so you don't waste too much time:

```
CREATE TABLE PriceHistory(
id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
product_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
price_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO PriceHistory(product_code, price, price_date) VALUES
('P01', 10, '2019-01-01'),
('P01', 15, '2019-01-03'),
('P01', 20, '2019-01-05'),
('P01', 15, '2019-01-09'),
('P02', 10, '2019-01-04'),
('P02', 15, '2019-01-06'),
('P02', 15, '2019-01-07'),
('P03', 15, '2019-01-09'),
('P04', 15, '2019-01-01'),
('P04', 15, '2019-01-02'),
('P04', 25, '2019-01-05'),
('P05', 15, '2019-01-01'),
('P05', 15, '2019-01-02');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `P01` changed price also on `2019-01-03`, why is it not showing in the result?

Comment: Also `P02` changed price on `2019-01-06`

Comment: And finally: `P04` changed price only once, on `2019-01-05`

Comment: @GMB I want the last change of each product, not every change.

Comment: How do you define the *last* change?

Comment: The price_date. For example, the last update for P01 was 2019-01-09.

Comment: So why do you have two records for `P01` and `P04` in the resultset, and no record for `P02`?

Comment: P02 have the same price 15 in its last 2 records, there was no change

Comment: OK this is getting clearer, but still more questions: `P01` has three consecutive price changes in the last prices (`15 > 20`, `20 > 15`, `15 > 10`), so if I followed you correctly we should get three records instead of two. And `P04` has just one price change (`25 > 15`), so we should get one record instead of two.

Comment: I just need the penultimate price and last price of each product only if they are different, if they are the same i ignore them.

Comment: OK. I updated my answer, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not precisely the exact answer because I expect to have the results on each row but this answer is good enough and get the job done:

```
SELECT info1.*, info2.* FROM
(SELECT lasts.product_code, lasts.id AS last_id, penultimate.id AS penultimate_id FROM
    (SELECT product_code, MAX(id) AS id FROM PriceHistory GROUP BY product_code HAVING COUNT(product_code) > 1) lasts
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT product_code, MAX(id) AS id FROM PriceHistory WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM PriceHistory GROUP BY product_code) GROUP BY product_code) penultimate
ON lasts.product_code = penultimate.product_code) relations
INNER JOIN PriceHistory info1 ON relations.last_id = info1.id
INNER JOIN PriceHistory info2 ON relations.penultimate_id = info2.id
WHERE info1.price != info2.price
```

And gives this result:

```
+----+--------------+-------+---------------------+----+--------------+-------+---------------------+
| id | product_code | price | price_date          | id | product_code | price | price_date          |
+----+--------------+-------+---------------------+----+--------------+-------+---------------------+
|  4 | P01          | 15.00 | 2019-01-09 00:00:00 |  3 | P01          | 20.00 | 2019-01-05 00:00:00 |
| 11 | P04          | 25.00 | 2019-01-05 00:00:00 | 10 | P04          | 15.00 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------+-------+---------------------+----+--------------+-------+---------------------+
```